# Where to find pronghorn sheds?

Tags: united-states, animals

Each year pronghorn shed the outer covering of their horns, and while they don't last as long as deer sheds you can still find them.

All of the ones I have found have been by accident, if one was to deliberately go looking for them, where would be good places to look?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know any places around you that usually host pronghorns, I would suggest search for them in grasslands, brushlands or desert areas around you, since that's where they feed and spend most of their time. Good luck!

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a more specific answer.  Pronghorns range over larger areas.  Searching all of the area they cover would be impractical.  A better answer would say something like look under willow trees, because pronghorns are known to prefer this for rubbing their horns on as they prepare to shed. (**P.S. This is an example, I just made up the reasoning**)